# Somar valores das colunas de lista de objetos em Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Possuo uma tabela, onde recebo os dados de uma View (SQL Server) e realizo algumas operações em minha página.
Nesta página, possuo um um filtro, para mostrar somente as páginas referentes ao ano selecionado.

Até esta parte esta tudo correto, juntamente com o filtro, como pode ser [visto neste exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/randrade/gf8k43n7/1/).

As operações são realizadas, inteiramente em minha View, que segue abaixo:

```
<table id="item-list" class="item-list table" style="margin-bottom: 0px;" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">
                Mês
            </th>
            <th rowspan="2">
                Remuneração<br />
                Total R$
            </th>
            <th colspan="4">
                <p align="center">
                    Contribuinte
                </p>
            </th>
            <th colspan="4">
                <p align="center">
                    Município
                </p>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr  bgcolor="#ffffff">
            <th>
                %
            </th>
            <th>
                Mês R$
            </th>
            <th>
                Ano R$
            </th>
            <th>
                Acumulado R$
            </th>
            <th>
                %
            </th>
            <th>
                Mês R$
            </th>
            <th>
                Ano R$
            </th>
            <th>
                Acumulado R$
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @*Variáveis para somar os totais dos campos*@
        @{
            double totalContribuinte = 0;
            double totalMunicipio = 0;
        }

        @foreach (var item in Model.Previdencia.GroupBy(g => new {g.NmPessoa, g.dtCompetencia.Value.Year}))
        {
        @*Variáveis para somar os totais dos campos por ano*@
            double subtotalContribuinte = 0;
            double subtotalMunicipio = 0;

            foreach (var contribuicoes in item.ToList())
            {

            @*Realizam as somas dos campos*@
                subtotalContribuinte += contribuicoes.Contribuinte;
                totalContribuinte += contribuicoes.Contribuinte;

                subtotalMunicipio += contribuicoes.BaseCalculo;
                totalMunicipio += contribuicoes.BaseCalculo;

            @*Adiciono a classe igual a selecionada no select*@

                <tr class="@contribuicoes.dtCompetencia.Value.Year" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                    <td align="right">
                        @contribuicoes.dtCompetencia.Value.Month.ToString("00")
                    </td>
                    <td align="right">
                        @contribuicoes.BaseCalculo.ToString("N")
                    </td>
                    <td align="right">
                        11
                    </td>
                    <td align="right">
                        @contribuicoes.Contribuinte.ToString("N")
                    </td>
                    <td align="right">
                        @subtotalContribuinte.ToString("N")
                    </td>
                    <td align="right">
                        @totalContribuinte.ToString("N")
                    </td>

                    <td align="right">
                        11
                    </td>
                    <td align="right">
                        @contribuicoes.BaseCalculo.ToString("N")
                    </td>
                    <td align="right">
                        @subtotalMunicipio.ToString("N")
                    </td>
                    <td align="right">
                        @totalMunicipio.ToString("N")
                    </td>
                </tr>

            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Minha `ViewModel` utilizada, com os campos:

```
public class ExtratoPrevidenciaViewModel
    {
        public int Codigo { get; set; }
        public int CdMatricula { get; set; }
        public Int16 SqContrato { get; set; }

        public string NmPessoa { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? dtCompetencia { get; set; }

        public double Contribuinte { get; set; }
        public double Municipio { get; set; }
        public double BaseCalculo { get; set; }

    }
```

Meu problema: Como realizar a soma de todos os valores, por coluna, separando por ano, como está o meu  `GroupBy` ?

O resultado final esperado, [seria algo parecido com isso.](http://jsfiddle.net/randrade/7s75o3g4/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No seu lugar, usaria mais uma `<tr>` para totalizar, mais ou menos assim:

```
<tbody>
    @*Variáveis para somar os totais dos campos*@
    @{
        double totalContribuinte = 0;
        double totalMunicipio = 0;
    }

    @foreach (var item in Model.Previdencia.GroupBy(g => new {g.NmPessoa, g.dtCompetencia.Value.Year}))
    {
    @*Variáveis para somar os totais dos campos por ano*@
        double subtotalContribuinte = 0;
        double subtotalMunicipio = 0;

        foreach (var contribuicoes in item.ToList())
        {

        @*Realizam as somas dos campos*@
            subtotalContribuinte += contribuicoes.Contribuinte;
            totalContribuinte += contribuicoes.Contribuinte;

            subtotalMunicipio += contribuicoes.BaseCalculo;
            totalMunicipio += contribuicoes.BaseCalculo;

        @*Adiciono a classe igual a selecionada no select*@

            <tr class="@contribuicoes.dtCompetencia.Value.Year" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                <td align="right">
                    @contribuicoes.dtCompetencia.Value.Month.ToString("00")
                </td>
                <td align="right">
                    @contribuicoes.BaseCalculo.ToString("N")
                </td>
                <td align="right">
                    11
                </td>
                <td align="right">
                    @contribuicoes.Contribuinte.ToString("N")
                </td>
                <td align="right">
                    @subtotalContribuinte.ToString("N")
                </td>
                <td align="right">
                    @totalContribuinte.ToString("N")
                </td>

                <td align="right">
                    11
                </td>
                <td align="right">
                    @contribuicoes.BaseCalculo.ToString("N")
                </td>
                <td align="right">
                    @subtotalMunicipio.ToString("N")
                </td>
                <td align="right">
                    @totalMunicipio.ToString("N")
                </td>
            </tr>

        }

        <tr>
            <td>Totais</td>
            <td>@item.Sum(c => c.BaseCalculo)</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@item.Sum(c => c.Contribuinte)</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@subtotalContribuinte.ToString("N")</td>
            <td>@totalContribuinte.ToString("N")</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@subtotalMunicipio.ToString("N")</td>
            <td>@totalMunicipio.ToString("N")</td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Comment: Após vendo a sua resposta, verifiquei que estava no caminho certo, e o problema estava no meu filtro js. Mas foi exatamente isso. Obrigado pela ajuda novamente.